# Values in a list to a new dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have my data as list say

```
r1=[['Pearson Chi-square ( 4.0) = ', 1021938.0], ['p-value = ', 0.0], ["Cramer's V = ", 1.0]]
```

I want to extract  4.0 inside this colon 'Pearson Chi-square ( 4.0)' and form a seperate column as DOF

I want to extract  1021938.0 inside this bracket

> 'Pearson Chi-square ( 4.0) = ', 1021938.0 and form a seperate column
> as Chisquare
>
> ['p-value = ', 0.0] as 0.0 and form a column called Pvalue
>
> ["Cramer's V = ", 1.0] as 1.0 and form a column Cramer's V

So that my output df will be

df

```
DOF  Chisquare    Pvalue   Cramers'V

4     1021938.0     0.0     1.0
```

I have tried this line of code

```
    DOF=r1[0][1]
    chisquare_stat=r1[0][0]
    p_value=r1[1][1]
    cramers_v=r1[2][1]
```

I need some help in extracting individual values alone and write it as a new df for easy refernce.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new df whit

```
from pandas import DataFrame
new_df = pd.DataFrame(r1)
T = new_df.T # Transpost the new_df
var = df[1].values
i_want = var[0]
i_want
```

the output is

```
1021938.0
```

This code make a uggly DF in my opinion you can create a new df whit a dictonary... anyway
I think the metod `df['column'].values` should fix the problem you also can use Transposed matrix its always helpfull